# Insert Rows in Word table

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I have a code which allows me to open a word application and create a table with 4 columns and 10 rows.

Is it possible with VBScript to insert new rows between the existing ones? I couldn't find the command for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rows.Add method has an optional parameter BeforeRow. Pass it the Row object of the row that should follow the new Row. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838946.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396